# Disable log4j console logging and enable file logging

Tags: java, logging, log4j

My log4j.properties file is:

```
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, stdout, file
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %p [%c] - %m%n

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=${jboss.server.log.dir}/afrodite.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.Append=true
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %p [%c] - %m%n

log4j.logger.info.release.scheduler=INFO, scheduler
log4j.appender.scheduler=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.scheduler.File=${jboss.server.log.dir}/afrodite_scheduler.log
log4j.appender.scheduler.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.scheduler.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.scheduler.Append=true
log4j.appender.scheduler.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.scheduler.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %p [%c] - %m%n
```

If I want to disable console output for **scheduler logger** what should I do? That means scheduler logger only log into file not in console.

Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this line to your config:

```
log4j.appender.scheduler.additivity=false
```

```
log4j.additivity.info.release.scheduler=false
```

(sorry, first hint was incorrect.)

Comment: How do you do this from within Java?

Answer (score 1):

you can add two lines in your properties file.

```
log4j.rootLogger=ALL, stdout, file,scheduler   (#here ALL declare for all level of logs)

log4j.logger.info.release.scheduler=INFO, scheduler
log4j.additivity.info.release.scheduler=false
```