# java log is not written into text file

Tags: java, logging

I have written a common class for logger and used this class in another class(Server_imp) to create logs. But no data is written in the text file instead it is shown on console.
What are problems with my code?
actually i have to create three log files for three different servers and log the functions performed by server managers .
and how i can stop data to be written on console?

```
public class MyLogging {
    static Logger logger;
    public Handler fileHandler;
    SimpleFormatter plainText;

        public MyLogging() throws IOException{
            //instance the logger
            logger = Logger.getLogger(MyLogging.class.getName());
            //instance the filehandler
            fileHandler = new FileHandler("D:/JAVA/assignment1/Montreallog.txt",true);
            //instance formatter, set formatting, and handler
            plainText = new SimpleFormatter();
            fileHandler.setFormatter(plainText);
            logger.addHandler(fileHandler);

        }

    }

//I have not copied the whole code

    public class Server_imp extends UnicastRemoteObject implements ServerInterface
    {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyLogging.class.getName()); 
    public void createTRecord(String f_name,String l_name,String addr,String number,String spec,String loc)
        {
    logger.info("Teacher record created");
        }
```

Comment: Do you think  `fileHandler = new FileHandler("D:/JAVA/assignment1/Montreallog.txt",true);` has the correct file path? Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059383/file-path-windows-format-to-java-format to give file path properly

Comment: can  you tell me how i can stop data to be written on console

Comment: path is fine as it works when i write this code in the file where i call it

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12067370/log4j-how-do-i-stop-my-logger-from-printing-to-the-console

Comment: nothing worked for me