# I can't modify or disable SLF4J log from log4j.properties

Tags: java, eclipse, log4j, slf4j

I'm looking for a way to disable log4j.properties file. I've found out some online solution, but none works:

[Disable log4j console logging and enable file logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095992/disable-log4j-console-logging-and-enable-file-logging)

[Disabling Log4J Output in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571960/disabling-log4j-output-in-java)

I've followed this tutorial tutorial [SLF4J Tutorial for Beginners](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/slf4j/slf4j-tutorial-beginners/) , but I didn't find a way to modifiy or to disable logging.

I'm developing OPCUA UA Stack client ,using  Unified Architecture Java Stack and Sample Code.
org.slf4j, SLF4J logging facade is a dependency mandatory.

In my Maven project, I'm using together to the SLF4J dependency the below dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.25</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

log4j.properties is:

```
# Normal log properties - Logs Warnings, Errors and Severe
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout

# Print info messages
log4j.logger.org.opcfoundation.ua=INFO

# stdout outputs to System.out. 
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
# stdout uses PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
# The conversion pattern uses format specifiers. You might want to
# change the pattern an watch the output format change.
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r %-5p [%t] %37c %3x - %m%n

# stderr outputs to System.err. 
log4j.appender.stderr=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stderr.target=System.err
# stdout uses PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.stderr.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
# The conversion pattern uses format specifiers. You might want to
# change the pattern an watch the output format change.
log4j.appender.stderr.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r %-5p [%t] %37c %3x - %m%n
```

I tested different solution,
I've tried to delete files from this path, but it's carrying on to print the same Pattern.

[image]

I modify the conversione pattern in the file, but it didn't work

```
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r %-5p [%t] %37c %3x - %m%n
#log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1} - %m%n
```

if I run the application with The second statement, on console I'll always the first ConversionPattern.
It seems to take the layout somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You could turn off the [ORMLite](https://ormlite.com/) messages specifically by adding the following to your `log4j.properties` file

```
log4j.logger.com.j256.ormlite=INFO
```

cheers buddy